# 2009 Kia Rio Radio seems to not be able to get a signal (no sound)

Tags: audio, kia, rio

I have a 2009 Kia Rio. Recently the car radio stopped working. The unit powers on, all the buttons/display seem to work normally, but the radio scans for a station with no sound. No, static, nothing. When a cd is inserted, the sound system plays the CD normally. All The fuses seem to be in good condition. Do you know what the issue could be?

Comment: Check if there is power getting to the antenna amplifier, if it has one.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happen to me. Radio seemed to work but no sound. Pulled and checked all the fuses with no success. My last chance effort paid off. I disconnected the negative wire from the car battery. After a short wait, I reconnected the wire. 
The sound is now on and all seems OK.